# GitHub Page Custom Domain - www is redirected to https

Tags: https, github, namecheap

I have a custom domain http://jstock.org mapped to my github page : http://yccheok.github.io

I setup it using https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages

My namecheap setup is

```
A Record    @    192.30.252.153 
A Record    @    192.30.252.154
CNAME Record    www    yccheok.github.io.
```

[image]
I also have a CNAME file setup at github side, which I believe it is being done correctly

https://github.com/yccheok/yccheok.github.io/blob/master/CNAME

However, when I type

```
www.jstock.org
```

it is redirected to

```
https://jstock.org
```

This will yield error in client browser, as my static page doesn't support SSL.

I was wondering, what is the root cause of this problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your site with www subdomain, then make sure your CNAME file in github pages also contain www, not just `domain.org`

So make your CNAME file like this

```
www.yourdomain.org
```

If the problem still exist, then may be your index.html might contain some javascript code which make automatic redirection. But first try above solution.